# How does batching helps in stream processing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is the advantage of processing data stream in batches over processing every data element in data stream? Why is it not possible to apply processing on each data item as it arrives?

[DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams) uses this concept in Spark Streaming.